# Start for mysql Query PHP

Tags: mysql

I'm currently looking to have a mysql query retrieve data and have and a start and limit.

So like, `select * from table where x = x START AT ID X LIMIT X`

thanks :)

Comment: why did you tag the question with `php` then, if it is not php-related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE x = x
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT x, x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `colName`='someVal' LIMIT 0, 10
```

The first limit value is the starting record number.  The second value is the number of records to query.